# How can I perform Search Functionalities after loading the data from API using button?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Task is that display the response in table format on the HTML and also make a search box to search for data in the table along with sorting capability.

Data get's load but search functionalities is not working.

I need to click the button and it loads the data and perform the search accordingly.

```js
var items = []

const load = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        const data = await response.json()
        items = data
        display(data)
    } catch (error) {
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = `Error: ${error}`
    } 
    search();
}

const display = (data) =>{
    var table = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var rowData ="<tr><td>"+data[i].userId+"</td><td>"+data[i].id+"</td><td>"+data[i].title+"</td><td>"+data[i].body;
        table+= rowData;  
    }
    document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = table;
}

// Search Function
const search = () =>{
    const table = document.getElementById('table');
    const mySearchField = document.getElementById('mySearchField');
    // const searchCharacters = []

    mySearchField.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
        const searchString = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
        const filteredItems = items.filter((data) => {
            console.log(data)
            return (
                data.body.toLowerCase.includes(searchString) ||
                data.title.toLowerCase.includes(searchString)
            )
        });
        display(filteredItems);
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3 id="demo">Let's Load the Data</h1>
        <button type="button" id="btn" style="color: white; border-radius: 2px; background-color: blue;" onclick="load(); ">Load Now!</button> 
        <input id="mySearchField" name="search" placeholder="Search.." type="text">
        <button id="mySearchButton">Search</button>
        <br><br>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">UserId</th>
                  <th scope="col">Id</th>
                  <th scope="col">Title</th>
                  <th scope="col">Body</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id="table">
            </tbody>
          </table>
    </body>

    <script src="./script.js">


    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more, what the issue is.. You have called the search function inside load(). So search will work only when you click on the load button.

Comment: You need an open/close parenthesis on the `toLowerCase()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the following change in your Search function (add **() brackets** when using toLowerCase() function).  It should fix the search issue.

```
return (
        data.body.toLowerCase().includes(searchString) ||
        data.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchString)
       )
```

Whole function will look like this:

```
// Search Function
const search = () =>{
    const table = document.getElementById('table');
    const mySearchField = document.getElementById('mySearchField');
    // const searchCharacters = []
    mySearchField.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
        const searchString = e.target.value.toLowerCase();

        const filteredItems = items.filter((data) => {
            console.log('11',data, searchString)
            return (
                data.body.toLowerCase().includes(searchString) ||
                data.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchString)
            )
        });
        display(filteredItems);
    });
}
```